# Google Translate API Detecting Wrong Language with Greek Translation

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I have set up functionality in one of my php applications to use the google translate api.  Seems to be working pretty good for single and multiple translation requests using both POST and GET methods...

The API does seem to have issues auto detecting many of my Greek strings as being English with very low confidence when I don't supply a source language...  One example is this string.

Σε προσωπικό επίπεδο συζητάμε με τους πελάτες. Διοργανώνουμε πεζοπορίες στα μονοπάτια που έχουμε διανοίξει και σηματοδότηση και εξηγούμε όλα τα περιβαλλοντικά ζητηματα

My application is not always aware of the actual source language, so I'm trying to get this to work with auto language detection.

The translate.google.com interface seems to have no problem detecting these strings however...

Does the API use a separate detection algorithm than translate.google.com?

Any info or suggestions on helping the auto detection work better?

Actual Request for above greek string:

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=%CE%A3%CE%B5+%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%83%CF%89%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C+%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%AF%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%B4%CE%BF+%CF%83%CF%85%CE%B6%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%AC%CE%BC%CE%B5+%CE%BC%CE%B5+%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%82+%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%AC%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%82.+%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B3%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%8E%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%B5+%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%B6%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%B5%CF%82+%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B1+%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%AC%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%B1+%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%85+%CE%AD%CF%87%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%B5+%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%AF%CE%BE%CE%B5%CE%B9+%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9+%CF%83%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%B4%CF%8C%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7+%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9+%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%B7%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%8D%CE%BC%CE%B5+%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%B1+%CF%84%CE%B1+%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%B2%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC+%CE%B6%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1&target=en&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

And Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [{
              "translatedText": "Σε προσωπικό επίπεδο συζητάμε με τους πελάτες. Διοργανώνουμε πεζοπορίες στα μονοπάτια που έχουμε διανοίξει και σηματοδότηση και εξηγούμε όλα τα περιβαλλοντικά ζητηματα",
              "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"}]
    }
}
```